# Too much data in a Python dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary, loops

I have a text file with about 10,000 lines.
A typical line look like this:

```
'1 2/1/2011 9:30,ZQZ,200.02,B,500'
```

If I run #1, I can iterate through the entire file, and `i` will count the total number of lines in the file.  However, if I create a dictionary which records the data in each line as I iterate through the file (as in #2) I will get about half way through.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.  Is it possible that 10,000 lines of data is too large to contain within a dictionary?  How can I determine this?
    #1
    TheFile = open(file_name)
    TheFile.next()

```
i = 0
for l in TheFile:
   i += 1
   print i

#2
TheFile = open(file_name)
TheFile.next()
thedata = {}
i = 0
for l in TheFile:
   i += 1
   print i
   this_line = TheFile.next()
   the_info = this_line.split(',')
   the_ticker = the_info[1]
   #print type(the_info[1])
   #print this_line
   if the_ticker not in thedata.keys():
      thedata[the_ticker] = {}

   thedata[the_ticker]['trade'+ str(len(thedata[the_ticker]) + 1)] =
   {'the_trade_number':len(thedata[the_ticker]),
    'theTime':the_info[0],
    'thePrice':float(the_info[2]),
    'theTransaction':the_info[3],
    'theQuantity':int(the_info[4])}
```

The problem is #2 does not give me any errors, which is why I have trouble figuring out what the problem is

Comment: oh btw, I receive no errors in running the file, which is why I am having trouble determining the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks Sam.  I am new to this site.  Not exactly sure why I did this though, but figure you know what you are talking about.

Comment: The 10,000 lines alone, will take almost 700KB of memory. Then there's the overhead with the `dict`. Even assuming that this gets you to 1MB, that's not a lot of memory. We really need to see how you're creating this `dict`

Comment: Thanks @inspectorG4dget.  I will try to post my code in a way that is not too confusing.  Also, how do you know that 10,000 lines will occupy 700MB of memory?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof('1 2/1/2011 9:30,ZQZ,200.02,B,500')` returns `69` bytes. Simple algebra from there

Comment: just to clarify it's 700KB not 700MB! So should be manageable.

Comment: In either case, I don't think it should make a huge difference. I doubt that OP is working on some embedded system with highly constrained memory

Comment: @kuyan: you tested on `{i:'1 2/1/2011 9:30,ZQZ,200.02,B,500' for i in range(10000)}`, didn't you?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yeah, pretty much. I posted the comment because (for some reason) I thought that you said 700 MB instead of 700 KB in your above comment. I was mistaken, so I erased it, but for the record, it totaled to `786712` bytes.

Comment: @kuyan: yes I did, actually… and then I edited it before anyone saw (or so I hoped)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Oh, okay. Well, that typo led me to learn about `sys.getsizeof`, so in the end, that typo wasn't too bad.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I mis-typed MB instead of KB.  Learned how to use sys.getsizeof as well.  Posted my code for creating the dictionary.

Comment: what happens when you get "about half way through"? I have a feeling that your algorithm is just slow (I see quite a few performance bottlenecks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is right here in run #2:

```
for l in TheFile:
   i += 1
   print i
   this_line = TheFile.next()
```

`l` already has the current line, and then you get another line using `TheFile.next()`.  I bet that if you change `this_line = TheFile.next()` to `this_line = l`, you'll get the results you expect.

Comment: I bet you are right.  That explains why it would stop halfway through.  Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, OP's code doesn't "stop halfway through". It runs through the entire file and skips every other line in the file

Comment: @Sam Mussmann, still wondering why is it so important to "accept this answer"?

Comment: Wondering one more thing.  Everything is working as I would expect now.  I have loaded about 10,000 lines from a text file into an embedded dictionary structure.  If I access the values in one of the containing keys via IDLE (print it to screen), I return an embedded dictionary which has about 600 keys, each of which contain 6 keys with a single corresponding value each.  When I have this information printed to the console, the computer becomes very bogged down(cannot scroll).  What is the reason for this? and how can I avoid it? as I would like to work with even larger data sets in the future

Comment: My guess is that you are overloading IDLE's ability to display text.  I can't really say more without knowing more about your situation.  I imagine you can get around this by (a) only printing parts of your dictionary at once or (b) printing your dictionary to a file and inspecting the dictionary that way.